# What does this picture with a small blue box and ribbon in Visual Studio mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, symbols

What does this picture with a small blue box and ribbon in Visual Studio mean?

[image]

Example:

[image]

Comment: It's a protected field.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it does indeed represent protected fields.

I setup a project to see if I get the same icon, and I do, which seems odd because according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons) it looks like it should be an asterisk for protected fields, not a blue ribbon.

---

Your individual page inherits from the `Page` class, where you'll find these declarations:

```
protected bool AsyncMode { get; set; }
protected bool AspCompatMode { get; set; }
```

`Page` inherits from `TemplateControl` where you'll find this:

```
protected virtual int AutoHandlers { get; set; }
```

And `TemplateControl` inherits from `Control`:

```
protected ControlAdapter Adapter { get; }
```